# Access to TWebRequest.Content throws a ERangeError exception in an ISAPI DLL but not in a console application

Tags: delphi, isapi

I'm writing an ISAPI dll that handles POST requests from an IoT device.
In parallel I have written a console application that shares the same `TWebModule`.

The action that handles the requests needs to access the request content (`TWebRequest.Content`) because it is not parsed correcly by default.

Everything works fine when the program is built as a console application. However a `ERangeError` exception is thrown when I want to access the `TWebRequest.Content` in the ISAPI dll.

Here is an example of the Content property :

```
-----------------------------7d624e177018a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Date_Time"

06/09/2021 11:14:03
-----------------------------7d624e177018a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f"; filename="IV.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

"TagId";"TagName";"Value";"AlStatus";"AlType";"Quality"
4;"AAA";0;0;0;65472
5;"AAB";0;0;0;65472
35;"TEST_Index";0;0;0;65472
36;"Signal";21;0;0;65472

-----------------------------7d624e177018a--
```

Here is a sample procedure that reproduces the problem:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1WebActionItem1Action(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin   
  Response.Content:= Request.Content;   // Throws a ERangeError exception in ISAPI dll   
end;
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: *"because it is not parsed correctly by default"* Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Can start with debugging it. Ex, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190866/how-to-debug-an-isapi-extension-using-the-delphi-debugger